# Is the closure of isolated points of a set in the real topology countable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ under the standard topology are the union of a perfect set and a countable set. As part of this, I am trying to show that the isolated points of a closed set have a countable closure. Is this statement true? If not, what's a counter example showing otherwise?

I know that the isolated points themselves are countable because the isolated points can be covered by disjoint rational intervals. However, this argument does not generalize to showing the closure is countablebecause no such interval can be placed on a limit point of the isolated points. Clearly countable sets don't necessarily have countable closures but it seems that the additional assumption of isolation between points may be enough to get this result.

Comment: Do you mean it does not generalize to showing the closure is "countable"?  Because obviously the closure is closed.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in the second paragraph.

Comment: You actually don't need this to be true to prove the decomposition. So maybe you need another proof idea?

Comment: As Henno Brandsma said, you don't need it and anyway it's false. Instead, if $S$ is closed and uncountable, let $T$ be the the union of all bounded open intervals that have  countable intersection with $S$, and have rational endpoints. Then $T$ is the largest open set to have countable intersection with $S.$ Show that $S\backslash T$ is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ be the set of open intervals removed from $[0,1]$ in the construction of the Cantor set.

For $d=(a,b)\in D,$ let $(x_{n,a})_{n\in N}$ be strictly decreasing , converging to $a$; and let $(y_{n,d})_{n\in N}$ be strictly increasing, converging to $b$; with $x_{1,d}=y_{1,d}=(a+b)/2.$

Let $C$ be the Cantor set .

Let $E=C\cup \{x_{n,d}:n\in N\land d\in D\}\cup \{y_{n,d}:n\in N\land  d\in D\}.$

Let $F=\bar E.$ (I think $E$ is closed by I haven't verified it.)

Observe that the set $F^i$ of isolated points of $F$ is equal to $E\backslash C,$ but $\overline {F^i}$ includes the set $V$ of all the endpoints of the members of $D,$ and $\bar V=C.$ We conclude that $F^i$ is dense in $F.$ And $F$ is uncountable because $C\subset F.$

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.redalyc.org/articulo.oa?id=46815211. The answer is thus not necessarily. I haven't read the construction yet, but at least it's not in Spanish. Great question, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your link doesn't seem to work. Do you think you could fix that?

Comment: Oops, I did copy it wrong. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks Davey, looks like an interesting read.